# How to use yield call in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, call, redux-saga, yield

I am implementing fingerprint scanning in my RN app and I found a good tutorial for that but the code there has a syntax which I have never used - `yield call()`, however, I googled it and couldn't find a proper explanation for it. 
Here is the code:

```
if (isFingerPrintSupported === true) {
                        yield call(KeychainService.setCredentials, user_name, 
                                          JSON.stringify({ password }));
                    }
```

**Is there something else I can use instead in this case? if not then how can I import this or install in order to make it work?**

**EDIT(example code added):**

```
   componentWillMount() {
    let credentials = yield call(KeychainService.getCredentials);
    if (credentials && credentials.username)) {
        let isFingerPrintSupported = yield call(KeychainService.checkBiometricSupportednEnrolled);

        if (isFingerPrintSupported === true) {
            // show fingerprint alert on login page
            // and authenticate FingerPrint when user touch the sensor
        }
    } else {
        // else don’t show fingerprint option on login
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yield` can be used inside a generator function & it helps to pause and resume a function at any time asynchronously. Also Additionally it helps to return value from a generator function.

Check this [document](https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-simple-guide-to-understanding-javascript-es6-generators-d1c350551950) for more information.

`call` is redux-saga effects which help to make asynchronous calls. Check [this](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) for more information.

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* authorize(user, password) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(/** Api call */, user, password)
    ...
  } catch(error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Note**

If you don't want to use `yield`, you can directly call you API with params using `axios` or `fetch`.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: See my edited question and give me a suggestion how to use fetch instead .

Comment: do I actually need to import something for Yield?

Comment: ```yield``` should be used inside a generator function. also, you need to import redux-saga effects in order to use ```call```

Comment: Am I using it properly in the edit code? When i hover over the Yield syntax it doesnt display any details, it almost seems like i need to import something

Comment: you are not using it properly please check this - https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-simple-guide-to-understanding-javascript-es6-generators-d1c350551950.

Comment: I found the code here:https://www.folio3.com/mobile/blog/fingerprint-login-react-native/ this guys is using it in multiple places. If he is actually doing it wrong can you please tell  me how to use Fetch in my case-use the edited code. This Yield seems complecated to me.

Comment: Please help  !   !

Comment: @bmmf I'll check that let you know.